# Formula to return relative position of nth non-zero value breaks for n > 2?

Tags: google-sheets, named-function

I have been trying to put together a named function in Google Sheets that will output the relative position of a cell within a single row that contains the nth non-zero value.

| Day1 | Day2 | Day3 | Day4 | Day5 | Day6 | Day7 | 1st Non-0 | 2nd Non-0 | 3rd Non-0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 0 | 0 | 14 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 1 | 4 | 7 |
| 0 | 16 | 0 | 0 | 23 | 0 | 17 | 2 | 5 | 7 |

The first 7 columns in this example are my input, the last 3 columns are my desired output.

I have added a named function to Google Sheets that successfully does this task for the 1st and 2nd non-zero values, but for the 3rd and beyond, it returns an empty cell. The function is:

```
NTH_NZPOS(range,nth)
=let(s,tocol(range),
  iferror(
    index(
      reduce(,sequence(rows(s)),
        lambda(a,i,if(ne(index(s,i,1),0),if(isblank(a),{i},{a;i}),a))),
    nth,1),
  "")
)
```

I am sure that there is a small error in the above code preventing this function from working for n > 2, but I cannot seem to find the issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to replace index with chooserows, working function is this:

> NTH_NZPOS(range,nth)
> =let(s,tocol(range),   iferror(
> chooserows(
> reduce(,sequence(rows(s)),
> lambda(a,i,if(ne(index(s,i,1),0),if(isblank(a),{i},{a;i}),a))),
> nth),   "") )

Answer (score 1):

With the seven input rows in A1:G3, you can generate the desired last three columns from cell H2 using the following:

```
=byrow(A2:G3,lambda(row,filter(sequence(1,7),row<>0)))
```

Comment: Filtering is a neat  idea, but wouldn't it only work in the particular case of there being three non-zeroes?

Comment: Should work for any number of non-zeroes, I think... If the OP only wanted the first three (not totally clear from the question) then this could be achieved with ARRAY_CONSTRAIN...

Comment: By "work" I suppose I meant " produce exactly three columns" so yes, array_constrain if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging a formula, the first thing you should do is to remove all the `IFERROR` functions to see what error it is returning.

I recommend using `FILTER` instead of `REDUCE`.

##### Arguments

- `range`
- `nth`

```
=LET(_range,TOCOL(range),
     IFERROR(INDEX(
               FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(_range)),_range<>0),
               nth)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an array that has the column numbers and the data in it, then use QUERY to find the non-zero columns, with LIMIT 1 OFFSET x to return the desired one.  I copied your data, and duplicated it to test.

```
=query(
  {sequence(7), transpose($A7:$G7)}, 
  "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0"
)
```

[image]

This should work for any arbitrary number of non-zero values, but I believe QUERY throws an exception if it returns empty, so you'd need to catch that.

The OFFSET here is hardcoded, and I manually changed it to 1 and 2 to produce the next two columns, but it could be dynamically generated, just not sure of your actual requirements so I left it in its simplest form.  For instance, here is a lambda implementation that accepts the range and generates the array and offset from that.

```
=lambda(rng, query(
  {sequence(columns(rng)), transpose(rng)}, 
  "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0 LIMIT 1 OFFSET " 
  & column() - columns(rng) - 1
))($A7:$G7)
```

[image]

And if the data doesn't start in column 1:

```
=lambda(rng, query(
  {sequence(columns(rng)), transpose(rng)}, 
  "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0 LIMIT 1 OFFSET " 
  & column() - columns(rng) - column(rng)
))($B7:$H7)
```

[image]